# Word counter only counting last line of text files, rather than full file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm building out a script that reads a csv file, converts it into a dictionary with a verb as the key and 0 as all values, then goes through plain text files of lyrics. If a verb from the dictionary is present in the lyrics, then it'll go ahead and +1 to the value associated with the verb.

Pretty much a word match + count.

The issue I'm currently facing is that when I run the script and it only reads the last lines of the two files I'm testing this out with. Here's the code...

please note that I'm going to optimize the 'line.replace' parts lol—

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv("List2dict.csv", header=None, index_col=0, squeeze = True) ##read list of verbs
verb_dict = df.to_dict()

path = "/Users/USERNAMEHERE/Desktop/Python/Notes/LYRICS" ## where lyric files are
arr = os.listdir("/Users/USERNAMEHERE/Desktop/Python/Notes/LYRICS") ## list out actual filenames

## replacement_chars = {"(":"", ")":"", "!":"", ".":"", "?":"", "/":"", "'in":"ing", "in'":"ing", "a-":""} add this later ###

for filename in arr:
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), "r") as lyrics:
            for line in lyrics:
                line = line.strip()
                line = line.lower()
                line = line.replace("(", "")
                line = line.replace(")", "")
                line = line.replace("!", "")
                line = line.replace(".", "")
                line = line.replace("?", "")
                line = line.replace("/", "")
                line = line.replace("'in", "ing")
                line = line.replace("in'", "ing")
                line = line.replace("a-", "")
                words = line.split(" ")
    
            for word in words:
                if word in verb_dict:
                    verb_dict[word] = verb_dict[word] + 1
                else:
                    pass

    else:
        pass

print(verb_dict)
```

Now what it should do is read through the whole text file, then print the new dictionary with counted values. I know that this only reads the last line, because I added in some verbs to the lines of the lyric files, and only verbs in the last line were counted when I printed verb_dict.

I've checked to make sure it knows where we are in the correct directory, and thankfully we are. Other than that, I'm not entirely sure what went wrong. All I know is that it doesn't count at all when I remove squeeze=True, and breaks at the "for line in lyrics" part if I change 'filename.endswith(".txt"):' to 'filename.endswith(""):'

[This answer also didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042380/beginning-word-counting-program-only-produces-output-for-the-last-line-in-python)

Comment: your loop `for word in words` should be inside the `for line in lyrics`

Comment: Happened to all of us when we were beginner coders, no worries!